# Value of currency type colum is wrongly displayed in workflow email

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, email, designer-workflow

In my list, I have a column called "Cost" which is a currency type column. When a user creates a new item in the list, I send a workflow email. In that email, I use `[%Current Item:Cost%]` to pull up the value of "Cost" column. But in the email, it always shows `$0.00`.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the currency column value is not set in the begining. So we need a "Calculated" type column added to the Content type with the following formula in the text box:

```
=DOLLAR([Cost], 2)
```

It solves the problem.